# the stderr.log SSO Tomcat not showing credentials obtained

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, business-objects

I'm trying to set up SSO on SAP BI 4.3 SP3 environment.

Then get to the part where we have set up `global.properties` and entered the following lines in Tomcat settings (Java options):

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=c:\windows\bscLogin.conf 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=c:\windows\krb5.ini 
-Djcsi.kerberos.debug=true -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true
-Djcsi.kerberos.maxpacketsize=0
```

Also I changed on the `server.xml` file (in the port Connector port="8080" » I added `maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"`).

But When we restart tomcat, `stderr.log` does not contain the message ‘Credentials Obtained’.

Any idea what we could be doing wrong?

Thanks

I checked all the files and they seem being well configured.